# Capturing string into multiple properties with Ant

Tags: regex, ant

I need to map the standard Ivy dependency tag into its three properties (org, name ,rev).

The following code won't capture anything

```
<!-- <dependency\s+org="([^"]+)"\s+name="([^"]+)"\s+rev="([^"]+)".*/> -->
<regexp id="ivyPattern" pattern="&lt;dependency\s+org=&quot;([^&quot;]+)&quot;\s+name=&quot;([^&quot;]+)&quot;\s+rev=&quot;([^&quot;]+)&quot;.*/&gt;" />

<target name="capture" depends="ivy-config">

    <input message="Input dependency" addproperty="dependency" />

    <propertyregex casesensitive="false" regexp="ivyPattern" input="${dependency}" select="\1" property="org" />
    <propertyregex casesensitive="false" regexp="ivyPattern" input="${dependency}" select="\2" property="name" />
    <propertyregex casesensitive="false" regexp="ivyPattern" input="${dependency}" select="\3" property="rev" />

    <echo message="Dependency: ${dependency}" />
    <echo message="Org: ${org}" />
    <echo message="Name: ${name}" />
    <echo message="Rev: ${rev}" />

</target>
```

Test result:

```
 [echo] Dependency: <dependency org="org.apache.cxf" name="cxf-api" rev="2.7.12"/>
 [echo] Org: ${org}
 [echo] Name: ${name}
 [echo] Rev: ${rev}
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

As you can see, I have XML-escaped the pattern using an online resource (freeformatter.com).

Why isn't it working? Every regex tester says the (unescaped) pattern works great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following revised code works:

```
    <propertyregex casesensitive="false" input="${dependency}" select="\1" property="org" >
        <regexp refid="ivyPattern"/>
    </propertyregex>
    <propertyregex casesensitive="false" input="${dependency}" select="\2" property="name">
        <regexp refid="ivyPattern"/>
    </propertyregex>
    <propertyregex casesensitive="false" input="${dependency}" select="\3" property="rev">
        <regexp refid="ivyPattern"/>
    </propertyregex>
```

A declared regex must be referenced in a `regexp` tag with `refid` attribute